# Where am I losing randomness?

Tags: javascript

So I'm building a rock, paper, scissors game. I want to get math.random() to give me a random result that I compare to the one chosen by the user.

It mostly works. I even thought it fully worked for a while, but I'm losing randomness at some point.

To try it, I input a fixed "user" choice and ran the code a few hundred times with setInterval(myfunction, 20). They're always lopsided victories, and always with the same outcome:

If I run it with playerPick = 1, the computer always wins.

If I run it with playerPick = 2 or 3, the user always wins.

Can anyone see where I goofed?

```
//Global variable and constants.

const ROCK = 1;
const PAPER = 2;
const SCISSORS = 3;

//This is the game.

function whoWins(){
    const playerPick = 2; //for debugging, it can be 1, 2, or 3.
    const computer = computerPick();
    if (playerPick == computer){
        return draw();
    } else if (playerPick == 1 && computer == 2){
        return lose();
    } else if (playerPick == 2 && computer == 3){
        return lose();
    } else if (playerPick == 3 && computer == 1){
        return lose();
    } else {
        return win();
    }
}

//These are the inputs for the game.

rockButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    playerPick = ROCK;
    return whoWins()});
paperButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    playerPick = PAPER;
    return whoWins()});
scissorsButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    playerPick = SCISSORS;
    return whoWins()});

function computerPick() {
    let computerChoice = '';
    const getRandom = Math.random;
    if (getRandom() >= 2/3) {
        computerChoice = ROCK;
    } else if (getRandom() >= 1/3){
        computerChoice = PAPER;
    } else {
        computerChoice = SCISSORS;
    }
    return computerChoice;
}
```

I'm very new to all this, but still, this is not random.

Comment: You use the method Math.random on ``const getRandom = Math.random;`` You have to actually call the method (``Math.random()``), by leaving out the paranthesis you are just using a method reference and not actually generating a random number.

Comment: one bug ... you call `getRandom()` twice for each computerPick - though, that doesn't explain the ALWAYS part of the result

Comment: I'd consider multiplying `getRandom()` by 100 and dealing with integer values (e.g. > 66, > 33).  Fractions and computers can be tricky.

Comment: @Joe - huh? 1/3 and 2/3 are not tricky

Comment: I'd also use a single getRandom() for the entire `computerPick` call.  (Already mentioned)

Comment: @LukasBach they're calling the function later using `getRandom()` - but there's probably no need to call it multiple times in the one if-else statement

Comment: @JaromandaX I guess I'm scarred from other languages where integer promotion would turn things like 1/3 and 2/3 into zero or 1.  To me that's harder to read.  Or just generate a random whole number between 0-2.

Comment: @NickParsons Ah you're right, overlooked that.

Comment: by the way - your code does NOT behave as you say, however, it does bias the computer pick towards PAPER

Comment: @JaromandaX Yeah I just noticed that math.random needs to be written math.random(), then I made all the getrandom NOT be functions and it seems equally distributed now... How it was working before I don't know o.O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be a simple fix, as mentioned in the comments you need to call Math.random once, otherwise the probabilities are skewed.

I think the probabilities of a PAPER would have been 0.66 * 0.66 = ~ 44% with the original code, the probability of SCISSORS would have been 0.66 * 0.33 = ~ 22%. The new function should resolve this.

```js
const ROCK = 1;
const PAPER = 2;
const SCISSORS = 3;

// Original computerPick function
function computerPickOriginal() {
    let computerChoice = '';
    const getRandom = Math.random;
    if (getRandom() >= 2/3) {
        computerChoice = ROCK;
    } else if (getRandom() >= 1/3){
        computerChoice = PAPER;
    } else {
        computerChoice = SCISSORS;
    }
    return computerChoice;
}

// Fixed computerPick function.
function computerPick() {
    let computerChoice = '';
    const choice = Math.random();
    if (choice >= 2/3) {
        computerChoice = ROCK;
    } else if (choice >= 1/3){
        computerChoice = PAPER;
    } else {
        computerChoice = SCISSORS;
    }
    return computerChoice;
}

function decodeChoice(choice) {
    if (choice == ROCK) return "Rock";
    if (choice == PAPER) return "Paper";
    if (choice == SCISSORS) return "Scissors";
}

// Check the distribution of each version of the code.
console.log("Checking distributions (10000 picks)..");
let original_counts = {};
let counts = {};
for(let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  let k = computerPick();
  counts[k] = (counts[k] || 0) + 1;
  let k2 = computerPickOriginal();
  original_counts[k2] = (original_counts[k2] || 0) + 1;
}

console.log('Computer Pick Distribution (original): ', Object.entries(original_counts).map(([key,value]) => `${decodeChoice(key)}: ${value}`));
console.log('Computer Pick Distribution (fixed): ', Object.entries(counts).map(([key,value]) => `${decodeChoice(key)}: ${value}`));
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, that fixed it. I'm not sure what the second part of the code does though (starting at const getRandom...). Is it just to check the distribution?

Also I notice you use math.random at the top and math.random() at the bottom (with and without brakets). What's the difference?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry @Billedale, I might just need to cleanup the code a little :).. yes the second part checks the original distribution version the fixed version. We can see your original version gave PAPER around a 44% chance and SCISSORS something like 22% (0.66 * 0.33). It's a very subtle bug!

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, you might find it easier to work with an array.

```js
const getRandomChoice = () => {
  const options = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'];

  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length);

  const choice = options[randomIndex];
  return choice;
}

const counts = {};

for(let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  let p = getRandomChoice();
  counts[p] = (counts[p] || 0) + 1;
}

console.log(counts);
```

By multiplying the result of `Math.random` by the length of the array (3) we can get a value that is between [0, 3) (not inclusive of 3). We then call `Math.floor` to "chop" off any decimals.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep it in mind. I just have one question, from what I understand from getRandomChoice, how is Scissors getting as many hits as the other two? Why isn't it cut off when you use Math.floor, since that rounds down to the nearest integer? So for example: randomIndex = 0.8*3 = 2.4 = 2 when Math.floor is applied?

Comment: @Billedale - It's getting just as many hits because the numbers being produced are 0, 1, & 2. Arrays are accessed starting at index 0, so there is an equal chance of them being hit

Comment: Think of it this way. `Math.random` generates a number between 0 and 1 (inclusive of 0, but not 1). So take the following examples

| 0.1 * 3 ==> 0.3 ==> 0 |

| 0.35 * 3 ==> 1.05 ==> 1 |

| 0.9999999 * 3 ==> 2.9999997 => 2 |

Comment: Ah! It's the start a 0 that confused me. Thanks a bunch, I'll definitely be using this in the future.